# MikTex 2.9 Serbian Cyrillic hyphenation problems

Tags: miktex, hyphenation, cyrillic

I have MikTex 2.9 on XP. Is there anybody to give me instruction how to set up program so that I can use serbian cyrillic hyphenation in it. I am not good in LaTex and I spent a lot of time trying to do it, but  without succes.

If I can use any other instalation in wich it works, please give me advice.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work on any up-to-date system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\begin{document}

% A sample text (source sr.wikipedia.org)
Београд је главни и највећи град Србије. Један је од 
најстаријих градова у Европи. Прва насеља на територији 
Београда датирају из праисторијске Винче, 4.800 година 
пре нове ере.

\bigskip

% the same text to show all possible hyphenation points
\noindent
\parbox[t]{0pt}{
\hspace{0pt}%
Београд је главни и највећи град Србије.
}\qquad\qquad\qquad
\parbox[t]{0pt}{
\hspace{0pt}%
Један је од најстаријих градова у Европи.
}\qquad\qquad\qquad
\parbox[t]{0pt}{
\hspace{0pt}%
Прва насеља на територији Београда датирају из 
}\qquad\qquad\qquad
\parbox[t]{0pt}{
\hspace{0pt}%
праисторијске Винче, 4.800 година пре нове ере.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anthon, thank you very much for your very quickly answer, but it does not work. Simply, doesn't work. :-(( 

Best regards 

Dragoljub

Comment: @Dragoljub Try looking at the MiKTeX wizard and its panel for enabling languages; maybe `serbianc` is not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Serbian Cyrillic hyphenation with babel package or polyglossia package.

**1. Babel example (and solution to a possible error)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\begin{document}

% A sample text (source sr.wikipedia.org)
Београд је главни и највећи град Србије.\\

\parbox[t]{0pt}{
\hspace{0pt}%
Београд је главни и највећи град Србије.
}
\end{document}
```

[image: image1]

If you get an error saying *no hyphenation pattern was loaded* there is a 'manual' workaround:

-find language.dat file (file location, in my case: C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\config) and add the following line to it:

```
serbianc loadhyph-sr-cyrl.tex
```

-run "initexmf --dump" without quotation marks in Command Prompt (run cmd.exe)

**2. Polyglossia example (use XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX engine)**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

% A sample text (source sr.wikipedia.org)
Београд је главни и највећи град Србије.\\

\parbox[t]{0pt}{
\hspace{0pt}%
Београд је главни и највећи град Србије.
}
\end{document}
```

[image: image2]

Don't know why the two examples give different results, but both work, in terms of hyphenation.

Comment: Even if you don't have enough reputation, please still upload the image and paste the link. Someone with edit privileges will re-embed the image.